# Azure DataBricks - webdriver installation best practices

Tags: python, selenium, pyspark, azure-databricks

What are the best practices regarding usage and installation of webdrivers in Azure DataBricks?

Currently I'm checking for the existence of `/tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver`, and if it does not, running the following:

```py
installCommands = [
  'wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver_linux64.zip -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip',
  'unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /tmp/chromedriver/',
  'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage',
  '/usr/bin/yes | sudo apt update',
  '/usr/bin/yes | sudo apt install chromium-browser'
]

if not exists(driverPath):
  print('Downloading and installing ChromeDriver')
  for command in installCommands:
    print(f'> {command}')
    system(command)
  print('Installation complete')
```

From what I've observed:

- the installation is specific to each notebook
- installations aren't persistent, depending on cluster liveliness? possibly frequency of runs?
- the download appears to cache, potentially same reasoning as above

Would storing and retrieving the unpacked driver in something like `dbfs:FileStore/WebDrivers/...` make more sense, or is there a better method of having persistent installations to be shared by multiple notebooks?

Edit: I've tried importing chromedriver_binary after installing the specific version I need (`chromedriver-binary==83.0.4103.39.0`) at the cluster level, but does not appear to work

Comment: Hello, 
I was thinking of similar solution recently but came to a conclusion that what I needed was the ETL process not Spark doing all the job, so I moved Extract to a separate module having selenium only (some enhanced Docker image like https://github.com/dimmg/dockselpy ). Then you can store results on some persistence (S3/warehouse/database) and analyze it with Spark later on.

Comment: yeah I think I agree with that approach - for my context adding a design that complicated (mainly different) would absolutely overwhelm the client, databricks is already a bit of a stretch haha. I've noticed that if I run all notebooks in series with the driver check as above, it only performs 1 download/install per pipeline run - definitely not ideal as it's a download each day, but probably good nuff